# How to use a data from the 1st API call and use that in my 2nd API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest, promise

```js
class TableData extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    TableData: [],
    show: false,
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };

  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://dev.meets.openhouse.study/meets_teachers/';
    axios.get(url).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ TableData: res.data });
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Room Name</th>
              <th>Teacher Name</th>
              <th>Subject</th>
              <th>Class</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          {this.state.TableData.map((data) => (
            <tr key={data.created_at}>
              <td>{data.room_name}</td>
              <td>{data.teacher.user.full_name}</td>
              <td>{data.subjects_str}</td>
              <td>{data.classes_str}</td>
              <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleShow}>
                Details
              </Button>
              <Modal
                size="lg"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                centered
                show={this.state.show}
                onHide={this.handleClose}
              >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                  <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                    Close
                  </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </Table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TableData;
```

I am making two API calls; 1st one is used for rendering a list of data in a table format. In each list there is a button. And while clicking the button I am trying to fire the 2nd Api(with a data property from 1st one).
How can I achieve this in Reactjs?

In the given code snippet - I am trying to view the data which is coming from the 1st API call and added a button to it. now I need to Fire a 2nd API call on Button Clik, in this URL - https://dev.meets.openhouse.study/room_participants/${room_name} (room_name will get from 1st API call).

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you've tried.

Comment: I have added the code snippet. please help

Comment: @ShankhadeepBhadra, On which button click you want to make a second API call?

Comment: <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleShow}>
                Details </Button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can bind an anonymous function for button onclick. From that method, we could call our component method like below.

```
<Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => this.getRoomInfo(data.room_name) }>
```

**Full code snippet:**

```
class TableData extends Component {
      state = {
        loading: true,
        TableData: [],
        show: false,
      };

      handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ show: false });
      };

      handleShow = () => {
        this.setState({ show: true });
      };

      getRoomInfo = (roomName) => {
        this.handleShow();
        const url = `https://dev.meets.openhouse.study/room_participants/${roomName}`
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
        });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'https://dev.meets.openhouse.study/meets_teachers/';
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
          this.setState({ TableData: res.data });
          this.setState({ loading: false });
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Room Name</th>
                  <th>Teacher Name</th>
                  <th>Subject</th>
                  <th>Class</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              {this.state.TableData.map((data) => (
                <tr key={data.created_at}>
                  <td>{data.room_name}</td>
                  <td>{data.teacher.user.full_name}</td>
                  <td>{data.subjects_str}</td>
                  <td>{data.classes_str}</td>
                  <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => this.getRoomInfo(data.room_name) }>
                    Details
                  </Button>
                  <Modal
                    size="lg"
                    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                    centered
                    show={this.state.show}
                    onHide={this.handleClose}
                  >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                      <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                        Close
                      </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                  </Modal>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </Table>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default TableData;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me a lot, Can I ask you another thing?

Comment: @ShankhadeepBhadra, Yes.

Comment: With your help, I can now see the data in console. I am storing the data in a state named roomData: []. But I want to map the data in the render function inside the previous map data. How can I do so? If you say I can send you the code snippet

Comment: state = {
    loading: true,
    TableData: [],
    show: false,
    roomData: [],
  };

Comment: @ShankhadeepBhadra, After the update of roomData state, the previous data won't be destroyed. Why because, the componentDidMonunt will not be called again. So, you will get roomData along with previous map data.

Comment: You can just populate the second api data in render method itself

Comment: I want to map the data inside the previous map function. Please I need your help please, can I share the code with you?

Comment: @ShankhadeepBhadra, Yeah, share in some code sandbox URL. That single file is enough

Comment: You are my God. This is my 1st job I don't want to lose it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-jones-ywf4y?file=/src/components/TableData.js

Comment: @ShankhadeepBhadra, Exactly where you want to render the 2nd api data?

Comment: After clicking the button in the modal I want to render the data of the 2nd API call

Comment: Please help me out Please 

Comment: In the popup what are the details want to display? I think we won't put the modal inside the loop

Comment: Then what can be the substitute? I need to submit it by today. Please help Please

Comment: in popup just want the room details, if you can help me out to see 1 or 2 details, rest I can manage - https://dev.meets.openhouse.study/room_participants/F91088C4C040

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-tdd-f32w2?file=/src/components/TableData.js - Find the updated code in this sandbox url. Here I moved the popup code to some generic functional component. There I pass the data which we got from second API call. There i just display the users full name.

Comment: Sir you are grt. Can I follow you on github?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215686/discussion-between-shankhadeep-bhadra-and-gokulakannan-t).